# Parse base64 to ReadStream nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64

Did some one know how I can parse base64 to ReadStream object WITHOUT saving it on the device by using NodeJs?
May be some one have alternatives?

Comment: Any code? What did you do so far.

Comment: Which code? I have base64 string(that was .wav file) AND want to convert it to ReadStream.
Sorry, but I cannot understand your question.

Comment: I think I understand what Daniel wants, although I couldn't answer for this question. He might read some file as a base64 string and want to convert it to file stream (something like format result of fs.read()) to send it to the other library. I have same question, but I think we're lack of understanding for file & data on memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can just push your string into a stream

```
var stream = new PassThrough();
stream.write(string);
stream.end();
```

But actually if you are reading from some other stream (downloading or reading from file) I would suggest just piping streams.